# Setdrawingmode(null) giving Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded main.js.27

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api

I have my google map codes running for time where I can draw polygon and polyline without issue. Below are my snippet of codes on how I do my drawing. Unfortunately I got this error Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded main.js.27. I notice that the error is at this line drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);. The moment I comment this line all works fine. Is there a bug in function now ?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
       if(e.type.toString()=="polygon"){
           var points = e.overlay.getPath();
           geoFenceString = "POLYGON((";
           var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           for (var i =0; i < points.length; i++) {
               var xy = points.getAt(i);
               latlngbounds.extend(xy); 
               geoFenceString = geoFenceString+xy.lng()+" "+xy.lat()+",";                         
           }
           geoFenceString = geoFenceString+points.getAt(0).lng()+" "+points.getAt(0).lat();     
           geoFenceString = geoFenceString+"))";
           var htmlString = '<table idth="100%">\r\n';
           htmlString += '<tr><td>Name</td><td valign="top"><input id="geoFenceName" type="text" style="width:100%" value=""></td></tr>\r\n';
            htmlString += '</tr>\r\n';
            htmlString += '</table>\r\n';
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            });

     }
     });
```

I can double confirm this because when I run codes from this link https://gist.github.com/rafalgalka/5765919 also give me same error.

Comment: Confirm that, I have found that while I use polygoncomplete and then use drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null); polygoncomplete enters infinite loop which is resulting in same error as above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046582/drawingmanager-setdrawingmodenull-causing-too-much-recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep a check before setting the drawingMode to null.

> if(drawingManager.setDrawingMode())
>   drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

That should work.

Comment: Nope ranadhir that does not work at all at it comes out with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue during january. I solved it with the logic "if drawing mode is already null, then don't try to set it to null again".

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    if (drawingManager.getDrawingMode() === null) {
        return;
    } else {
        ... do your stuff ...
    }
});
```

Usually "do your stuff" involves setting Drawingmode to null, so checking for a null drawing mode aims to check if you already "did your stuff".